# Trigger when a specific sheet tab is accessed

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I am trying to execute a code when a specific google sheet tab is accessed in my spreadsheet.

The native onOpen or onEdit triggers does not fire when a tab is clicked. I would like a trigger to run each time I access a specific tab.

How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

#### Run code when a selection is made in a specific sheet

```
function onSelectionChange(e) {
  ///Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  const ov = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("sheetname");
  const tv = "Sheet0";
  const cv = e.range.getSheet().getName();
  if(cv == tv && ov != cv) {
    e.source.toast(`cv = ${e.range.getSheet().getName()}, ov = ${ov}`)
    //Put your code in here this only is true when you have come from another sheet
  }
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('sheetname',cv);
}
```